# google maps how to add marker if I know the latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Before, I was adding the marker on click like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });
```

and that was working find, but now I want to add a marker depending on the latitude and longitude not depending on the click event.

I tried this:

```
if (("#latitude").val() && (("#longitude").val())){
    marker = new google.maps.marker({
    });
}
```

but I still don't know what parameter should I pass. Could you help me please?

many thanks

Comment: What will be the event that trigger the marking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Marker to Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery("#addmarker").bind("click", function(){
                console.log("Click");
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng( -34.397,150.644),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });

                var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"><h1>Overlay</h1></div>';
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });

                // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
                marker.setMap(map);
            });
        });     
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addmarker">Add marker</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line `if((("#latitude").val()) && (("#longitude").val())){`

Comment: Can you try again my code

Comment: thatnks for the efforts but I can't try  the whole code, I already have a complicated page and I just wanted to add the marker, but now as I told you I got an error message in the `if` statement. so I need to solve it in order to be able to access the `if` condition. then test your code. could you check the  error please? it is the first comment to this question. many thanks

Comment: Have you two element with ID `latitude` and `longitude` available?

Comment: Try this:

`if ( document.getElementById("latitude").value && document.getElementById("longitude").value )
    marker = new google.maps.marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng( document.getElementById("latitude").value,document.getElementById("longitude").value),
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
 });
}`

Comment: the problem is that the `latitude` and `longitude` are `display:gone` ? is that could be the problem?

Comment: +1 to the efforts, many thanks

Comment: No, debug with console that it will give value

Comment: okay I will try and update you

Comment: when I log the value, I can see it, let me try again and will update you.

Comment: I got `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` on this line `marker = new google.maps.marker({`

Comment: Fantastic -- I was returning this as a string, using parseInt(theLat),parseInt(theLong) I was able to get it working. Same thing for map centering too :D

Answer (score 0):

```
map.addOverlay(new GMarker(
    new GLatLng(-33.9417, 150.9473)));
var point = new GLatLng(-33.9417, 150.9473);
map.setCenter(point, 10);
var marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

http://javascript.about.com/library/blgmap05.htm

Comment: I got `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ` on this line `if((("#latitude").val()) && (("#longitude").val())){`

Comment: it is in the question not in the answer, that is important line to test your code

Comment: answer has been edited try again

Comment: Sorry, but your answer doesn't provide the `if` statement. the error message is in the `if` condition and I must solve it in order to test your code. I hope you got me

Comment: you should be using LatLng not #latitude and #longtitude

Comment: you don't need the if

Comment: the problem is that those ids have this style`display:none`, could that be the problem please?

Comment: +1 to the efforts, many thanks.

Comment: The posted code in this question is specific to the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), that version of the API should _not_ be used for new code.

Comment: @geocodezip what ?!!! I though I am using v3 not v2. how did you know please? and if i used v3, I would change my js code? :(

Comment: The answer under which I added this comment is using v2: GLatLng is a v2 object, addOverlay is a v2 method. (so ignore and/or downvote this answer, it is not useful to you if you are using v3)

Comment: @geocodezip of course I won't downvote to someone who take his/her time trying to help me. instead I have upvoted her answer. However, I am trying with the other answer, and I got exception, which I wrote in the last comment, could you check please?